# Generar un archivo LOGGING mediante System.Diagnostics. C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, app.config

Estoy tratando de generar un archivo **.log** mediante **System.Diagnostics** en un proyecto de consola.

El problema es que el archivo **.log** que genero, me lo devuelve vació.

Acá les dejo el código que utilizé en **.NET**:

```
TraceSource tr = new TraceSource("Wall-E", SourceLevels.All);
                tr.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Information, 1,
                    "Error message.");
```

Y acá le dejo la configuración que utilicé en el **app.config** del proyecto:

```
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="Wall-E">
        <listeners>
          <remove name="Default"/>

          <add name="consoleListener"
               type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener"/>

          <add name="eventlogListener"
               type="System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener"
               initializeData="Application"/>

          <add name="textfileListener"
               type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
               initializeData="Wall-E.log" />

          <add name="xmlfileListener"
               type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
               initializeData="Wall-E.xml" />

          <add name="defaultListener"
               type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Saludos